# Where should encryption occur - at application or database level?

Tags: java, sql-server, security, encryption

In order to protect sensitive data of a web-application the question arises whether it is best practice to encrypt on application level using jasypt (for Java) and save encrypted data to the database or to use the encryption mechanisms of (for example) MSSQL 2012?

Under the aspect of

1. Security concerns
2. Performance concerns

What is considered best practice here?

EDIT:

To give little more details about the type of application: It is a web-portal where users upload senstive data to the portal where this data is evaluated by the portal owner. It is going to be used at the customer site so we have limited control who has access to the servers and limited control of the application server,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all boils down to the question of trust. Do you control the application server fully? What is the threat level? How could the sensitive data be compromised on that level? Then, how is it on the db level? Can you control the db? What about who has access to it?

Your Question can't be answered in general. It all depends on the type of threats you want to be protected against.

- Generally, if you encrypt in the application it becomes hard to use efficient database retrieval techniques. Often, indexes stop to work in a meaningful way. Sorting becomes hard, etc...
- If you encrypt on the db level, you should think about a temporary encryption of the transport (think SSL or SSH tunnels)
- Performance should be a minor concern if you really want to protect the data. I am not an expert at this but I would think that there are well performing solutions for both, application data encryption as well as on the database level.

Answer (score 0):

In general data should be marshalled sent across network demarshalled at the other end. Then while storing the data you can actually encrypt it ans store.

Comment: Don't you think it should be dependent on the type of application? I mean if the data that is to be sent across is more sensitive then it should be encrypted as well as also in database. for example some top secret military data.

Comment: Yes and that is the exact reason i specified in general. Even if we consider simple data transfer via our network it is encrypted at presentation layer which comes immediately after application layer in seven layer OSI model. So you are right it is specific to user design and architecture requirement.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK ,there will be no major performance concerns, Since performance nothing to do with **encryption**.

And  the next step, regarding **security** concerns the data should be encrypt at code level,So that it ensures that `data` is secure while passing **through the wire**.

At the end that same `data` would be save in database. That will ensure security at both the place, through the **network** and as well at data container.

Comment: @SURESH ATTA "Since performance nothing to do with encryption". Really don't agree with this. Encryption algorithms are performance intensive and different implementations(Java/SQL based) can have different complexities.

Comment: @SURESH ATTA: Of course encryption has something to do with performance - at least it consumes processor time.

Comment: Yes, there will be a little time complexities but that advantages at both the ends *IMHO*